# Nested model forms; How to access the parent/root FormBuilder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, partial-views

I have the following rails erb code:

```
<% form_for @foo do |c| %>
  <% c.fields_for :bars do |builder| %>
  <%= render 'foo/bar_fields', :f => builder %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Inside the _bar_fields.erb partial I can access the FormBuilder of the nested model through the 'f' instance variable. Is there a way to access the 'parent'/'root' FormBuilder through that instance variable? Or is passing another local to the partial the only way?

Comment: Usually in the nested form you don't access the parent, what are you doing with it? (out of curiosity)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know you'd have to pass it through as another local.